# Stopping Hive server - Hortonworks hadoop

Tags: hive, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I have 3 hive server in my cluster. I would like to stop one of them as its not required. Do I need to completely remove it or just stopping would help?
as ZooKeeper returns one randomly-selected registered HS2. What if Zookeeper returns this stopped instance? Or zookeeper will check the state of hiveserver if its up or not and then it will return any hiveServer2?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper should be notified in the event of a clean shutdown for Hive, therefore not return it in a Hive URI request

If you don't need that server, then you should shut it down, and then uninstall Hive processes